# System thread inside a Timer in Android

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, timer, xamarin

So I have a `Timer` in my `Activity` and I want to run that every 10 seconds.

I created a `System.Threading.Timer`:

```
timer = new Timer ((o) => {
    Action syncAct = new Action (async delegate() {
        await FetchData();
    });

    RunOnUiThread (syncAct);
}, null, 0, 10000);
```

The problem here is that `await FetchData()` takes longer than 10 seconds and that causes the timer to go on forever. I need the timer to start every time AFTER the sync completes.  How can I do that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try spawning a thread that sleeps for 10 seconds and runs the code.

Roughly like so:

```
\\declare doRun as a boolean field
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        yourClass.doRun = true;
        while(yourClass.doRun)
        {
            fetchData();
            try {
                sleep(10000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e)
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Set `doRun` to `false` to exit the thread.
Or you could assign the thread to a variable instead of an anonymous thread, and call `yourThread.interrupt();`

Comment: So I would put that inside my `Timer`? I need this to repeat every 10 seconds.  And I am very new to this so a quick question. what does `sleep(10000)` do? I mean to say, does it still allow the user to use the `Activity` while it's sleeping? The app needs to be useable when this happens.

Comment: @user3866010, no, use this in place of your current code. The code I wrote will call your `fetchData()` method, and after the method finishes it will wait 10 seconds and run it again until `doRun` is false.